# Kayako - Loading Unoptimized Cache

Tags: php

I am getting the following error. Any solution to fix this?

```
Loading Unoptimized Cache: staffcache on Interface: 100 for App: base


SWIFT - 04 Dec 2017 05:18:28 PM
Router: https://myweb.com/cron/index.php?/Base/CronManager/Execute
_____________________________________________________________________________

Loading Unoptimized Cache: staffcache on Interface: 100 for App: base


SWIFT - 04 Dec 2017 05:18:29 PM
Router: https://myweb.com/cron/index.php?/Base/CronManager/Execute
_____________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: You might want to contact Kayako support to ask them what their warning means and what you can do about it.

Comment: Asked them already! I hope they reply quickly.

Comment: Have you tried a grep of their code to look for the warning text? That would tell you what test is failing.

Comment: This is now resolved. I have integrated elastic search within Kayako. This issue was due to some issue with elastic search service.